# What is the consensus about hijacking the accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, editing

I came across this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/170640/338915) yesterday.

There is two different answer to this question, one has been accepted. Let's call accepted answer [answer 1](https://askubuntu.com/a/170645/338915) and the other [answer 2](https://askubuntu.com/a/355102/338915).

---

Recently *answer 1* has [been edited](https://askubuntu.com/posts/170645/revisions) to include the content of the *answer 2*.

---

I don't know what to think about this. On one side I think it is unfair for *answer 2* creator because it won't get the upvote he deserve anymore.

But on the other side, as question *answer 1* is accepted answer, *answer 2*'s solution (which is better in my opinion) is going to have to better visibility.

---

I got a bit lost in my explanation, I hope I have been clear enough...

What is the general consensus about hijacking top answer for visibility ?
Is that encouraged ?

Comment: So from what I see it was edited by another user  and that's not exactly OK. If done by  the answerer him/herself would probably be OK, as long as it's not a full blown plagiarism of the second answer. Many times answerers revise their own answers to include alternative solutions or updated information

Comment: This happens in real-life conversations and it's a bit annoying:  someone who wishes to be seen as smarter will just parrot the latest/best answer that the crowd seems to like.  The nature of these forum-based systems allows people to silently edit their answers in order to be seen as smarter.  First response is best... because this allows them later to edit it to the latest wisdom.

Comment: I think I'd probably just put "See Answer 2 for alternative" or something to that.

Answer (score 15):

Upvote number 2, also I have edited out the attempt to merge the answers, as this does a disservice to the person who originally answered with answer 2 and gives votes to a mostly old answer that just happens to have the check mark - if answer one dosnt work anymore downvote it, or edit only to fix that method. If you have a new method use a new answer.

Answer (score 11):

tomodachi, who posted answer 1, had edited answer 2, so it is clear tomodachi was aware of the other answer. And since they didn't include that part in their answer: reject as "clearly conflicts with author's intent".